# How to change execution dir in Phing?

Tags: php, phing

Maybe I'm not getting something, but I couldn't find anywhere how to change execution dir for a specific target.

Here's my setup:

```
project
│   composer.json
│   build.xml
└───htdocs
    │   phpunit.xml
    ├───app
    │   │   bootstrap.php
    │   │   ...
```

I'm running `phing` from the project folder, but due to specifics in phpunit's bootstrap, I need `getcwd()` in bootstrap.php to resolve to `htdocs`.

Currently I've tried to add `exec` with `cd` inside - but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<target name="phpunit" description="Run unit tests" depends="install">
    <!-- move to app root before running tests -->
    <exec logoutput="true" command="cd ${app}" />
    <phpunit haltonfailure="false"
             haltonerror="false"
             printsummary="true"
             codecoverage="true">
        <formatter type="xml" todir="${project.basedir}/build/logs"/>
    </phpunit>
    <!-- Move back to project root -->
    <exec logoutput="true" command="cd ${project.basedir}" />
</target>
```

Is there such a concept in Phing (to change current dir)? Or is there another possible solution to change how `getcwd()` works inside the phpunit's bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to execute phing from htdocs with

```
 phing -f ../build.xml phpunit
```

Look for this build.xml example:

```
<project name="Test" basedir="." default="list">
    <target name="list">
        <getcwd />
    </target>

 <adhoc-task name="getcwd"><![CDATA[
      class GetcwdTask extends Task {
          function main() {
              print(getcwd());
          }
      }
  ]]></adhoc-task>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good example of thinking broadly and fixing the issue by accessing it from a different angle :) Upvoted, but maybe someone knows actually how to solve the switching directory if the need arises to have different root dirs for different targets

Comment: you can set -Dproject.basedir=/any/dir but then getcwd() always return /any/dir